# Google Tag Manager for iOS - 'Application Version' macro is not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

We're using GTM on our iOS apps to deploy and manage Universal Analytics.

To do this we've created a tag called "Open Screen" of track type "App View" and set three basic configuration parameters, Screen Name, App Name and App Version.

App Name and App Version are using the predefined Macros "Application Name" and "Application Version".  App Name is getting set fine, but for some reason Application Version is never getting set.

Viewing the GTM Response we can see that the &av parameter is only ever getting set to ""

As far as we can tell we've set it all up correctly but for some reason App Version is not getting through.  Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening here or how we can debug it more effectively?

Comment: It is tough to answer this question without example code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried blanking out the value in the App Version field in Basic Configuration?  It should automatically add that to the GA hit without any custom mapping.  You WILL have to set the Screen Name, so keep that mapping.